# Inserting a comma after every character in a string? Objective C

Tags: objective-c, string

Hello I'm receiving a string that contains a zipcode.
E.G. "34747" and I need to convert it to something like this "3,4,7,4,7"

What would be the best way to implement this in Objective C?

Comment: I would split it into an array of characters and then join it with the comma as a separator. In Swift it's a one-liner: `Array(zipcode).map(String.init).joined(separator:",")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Objective-C it's pretty awful:

```
NSMutableArray *characters = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:[myString length]];

for (int i=0; i < [myString length]; i++) {
    NSString *ichar  = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%C", [myString characterAtIndex:i]];
    [characters addObject:ichar];
}

NSString *output = [characters componentsJoinedByString:@","];
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! It worked pretty well although I agree Objective C's solution is way more awful than Swift's.